# What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}{\frac{n^2-7n+5}{n2^n}x^{3n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found 2 using the ratio test,is it true?

Comment: be careful, it is $x^{3n}$ not $x^n$. Radius of convergence is $2^{1/3}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}{\frac{n^2-7n+5}{n2^n}t^{n}}$ and show that this power series has radius of convergence $2$. This means that the power series $\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}{\frac{n^2-7n+5}{n2^n}x^{3n}}$ converges for $|x|^3 <2$.